# Difference between "is closed under" and "is stable under"?

Tags: terminology

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space it is said that

> A bornology on a set X is a collection ℬ of subsets of X such that
>
> - [...]
> - ℬ is stable under inclusions, i.e. if A ∈ ℬ and A′ ⊆ A, then A′ ∈ ℬ;

where "is stable under" sounds very much like the same as "is closed under" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics):

> A set is closed under an operation if performance of that operation on members of the set always produces a member of that set.

When do I choose which expression and what is the difference between those expressions?

Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)#Invariant_set related to "is stable under" and if so, how?

Comment: I would say that a subset $A' \subseteq A$ cannot be said to have been produced by "operation on members of the set"

Comment: My personal observation, based on mathematicians I have known.   "Stable" is what you say if French is your native language.  They may say "stable under countable unions" rather than the English way "closed under countable unions".

Answer (score 2):

“Closure” is about operations. For instance, the set $\Bbb N$, as a subset of $\Bbb R$, is closed under multiplication (the product of two natural numbers is always a natural number), but not under division (the quotient of two natural numbers is not alwyas a natural number).

However, this doesn't apply to inclusions, since inclusion is not an operation. Being “stable under inclusions” means that if $A$ belongs to your set and if $A'$ is a subset of $A$, then $A'$ also belongs to your set.

Comment: So,  "stable under X" means that X is a function with one input symbol and "closed under X" means that X is a function with two input symbols? (In both cases all symbols must be elements of the same set as the output of the respective functions.)

Comment: No. Let $P$ be a property. Being stable under a relation $\sim$ means that if $A$ has the property $P$ and if $A\sim B$, then $B$ also has the property $P$. Being stable under an operation $o$ means that if both $A$ and $B$ have the propery $P$, then $o(A,B)$ also has the property $P$.

Comment: I am not sure how this is different to what I wrote regarding functions. After all operations and stuff like unions are functions. I would say that a relation like "<" is also a function (where the boolean set is the codomain), but I am not sure. Can you give an example, maybe that helps me to understand what you mean. (Disclaimer: I am more an engineer / (so more applied math) than a pure mathematician.)

Comment: If you don't mind to work with functions which map elements into boolean values, then, yes, what you wrote is equal to what I wrote. It's just a matter of taste.

Comment: Ah, I start to see what you mean. In that case my first comment was wrong actually, because I said that "stable under" has one input symbol. Correct would be: "set S is closed under f" would bean that $f$ is a function $f: S \times S \rightarrow S$, while "set S is stable under f" would mean that f is a function $f: S \times S \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. Right?

Comment: Let us be more precise. The set $X$ is closed under $f\colon S\times S\longrightarrow S$ if $A,B\in X\implies f(A,B)\in X$. And it is stable under $f\colon S\times S\longrightarrow\{0,1\}$ if$$A\in X\text{ and }f(A,B)=1\implies B\in X.$$

Comment: Isn't the relation between $X$ and $S$ missing in those? Is $X\subseteq S$ in each case? Why not substitute $X$ with $S$ in the formulas?

Comment: I was assuming that $X\subset S$.

Comment: But then, couldn't I just substitute $S$ with $X$ in the function definition? So just write $f: X \times X \rightarrow X$ and $f X \times X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ instead? What would be the point of introducing the symbol $S$ at all?

Comment: Because what we are talking about is when a subset $X$ of a set $S$ is “stable” or “closed” with respect to something.

Comment: Let us use the case of bornological space as an example, so "$S$ is stable under inclusion", with $f$ is being the inclusion. So it would be $f: S \times S \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and $A \in S \wedge f(A,B) = 1 \Rightarrow B \in S$. I do not see the need for an additional set like $X$. Of course we could also have written $f: X \times X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and $A \in X \wedge f(A,B) = 1 \Rightarrow B \in X$ instead and then there would not be need a for a symbol $S$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112684/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-make42).

Comment: Not sure if you get a notification, when I write in the chat... (which I did).